# Amazon RDS Daily Snapshops without Automated Backups

Tags: amazon-rds

We have set up Amazon RDS. Performance is a bit slower than previous shared system, but it gives us more control regarding users.

How can we get automated daily snapshots (e.g. during the stipulated window) without having point in time features? We dont need the latter and it apparently affects performance by 25%. However, getting an automated snapshop every night would be useful.

Changed retention period to 0 which did speed up everything, but as feared it didnt do any snapshop overnight. I am aware of the possibility of manual snapshots, but would much prefer scheduled ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can we get automated daily snapshots (e.g. during the stipulated
>   window) without having point in time features?

You can't, these are tied together within their current design, i.e. there is no option to disable just the point-in-time recovery.

The reason likely is that the binary logs facilitated for this feature are required anyway as soon as you are using one of the replication options, e.g. *Multi-AZ deployments* and/or *Read Replicas*. These do require the very same binary logs used for the point-in-time recovery, which is why you can't set the retention period to 0  once they are enabled, see e.g. the parameter *BackupRetentionPeriod* for the [ModifyDBInstance Action](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyDBInstance.html):

> Constraints:
>
> - Must be a value from 0 to 8
>     *[meanwhile 35 btw. see [Amazon RDS Increases Backup Retention Period]](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/03/19/amazon-rds-increases-backup-retention-period/)*
> - Cannot be set to 0 if the DB Instance is a master instance with read replicas or if the DB Instance is a read replica

Accordingly you'll need to resort to a custom automation solution for the [CreateDBSnapshot Action](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBSnapshot.html).